# Python - Struct pack error

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to pack a alphabet, for example, A
I used struct.pack('c','A'), but the output kept showing

"struct.error: char format requires a bytes object of length 1"

I checked the official documents of all version of Python, the syntax are the same.
I'm using version 3.3.2.

Does anyone know what's wrong with it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

`'A'` is a `str`. You want `b'A'`, which is a `bytes`.

["Unicode In Python, Completely Demystified"](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/)